# Git, WSL2, SSH: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet

Tags: linux, ssh, git

While attempting to clone a remote Git repo using SSH I got the following error:

```
git clone user@remote-repo:project.git .
remote: Counting objects: 187444, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (73430/73430), done.
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe.06 MiB | 4.04 MiB/s
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

My environment has the following Specs:

- WSL2 (Windows Subsystem 4 Linux)
- `git --version git version 2.30.1`

The git package can be found here https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86_64/git

```
uname -a
Linux 4.19.128-microsoft-standard #1 SMP Tue Jun 23 12:58:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 Linux

2021-03-09-07:11AM wsl@Alpine:~$ more /etc/issue
Welcome to Alpine Linux 3.10
Kernel \r on an \m (\l)
```

I've got no clue why is this happening. Is it a bursting or kernel configuration issue on Alpine? WSL? I doubt it's the remote host. The remote host works fine for SSH, as well as cloning for every non-WSL user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WiFi networking card on my laptop was the root cause. My card is killer wifi but also read the same happening to Intel WiFi cards.

Upgrading the WiFi card drivers immediately fixed the issue.

Still completely lost on me how a networking drive ended up causing this strange git error issue.

Answer (score 3):

```sh
export GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
export GIT_TRACE=1
export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1

git config --global core.compression 0
git clone --depth 1 <repo_URI>
# cd to your newly created directory
git fetch --unshallow 
git pull --all
```

Comment: The trick was `git config --global core.compression 0`

Answer (score 3):

The trick for me was `--no-tags`:

```
git clone --no-tags ssh://git@stash.acme.com/repo/project.git
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to switching to different network and see if this problem persists. If my assumption is right, it's due to the low connectivity of your internet.

It's most likely due to bad internet, as evident by the following line:

```
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
```

Comment: I had same issue with `git push` and found that I had to disconnect my highspeed wired and wifi networks and connect to a cellular 4G network. Speed was much slower but it worked. Now I need to find a real solution.

Comment: @AW101 most likely your highspeed wired network had higher packet loss

Comment: You could be right, as after swapping out the router the problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced the same, particularly for larger repositories. The fix [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73079516/605067) has worked for me on multiple workstations:

Open git global config:

```
git config --global -e
```

And add these entries:

```
## Fix for fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
[core] 
packedGitLimit = 512m 
packedGitWindowSize = 512m 
[pack] 
deltaCacheSize = 2047m 
packSizeLimit = 2047m 
windowMemory = 2047m
```